# "instagram graph api" how to increase Number of Users of app?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm working with instagram graph api's business discovery and notice that rate limit depend on something call "Number of Users" of app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting?locale=en_US

I could not find clear description of what it is nor how to increase it.

Can anybody teach me how to increase "Number of Users"?